# RequiredFieldvalidator

Tags: asp.net

how to use required field validator for dropdownlist?.

my dropdown list having

-Day-

item1

item2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use InitialValue property as the default item that you don't want to be selected :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItems" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="-Day-" Value="-Day-"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1" Value="Item 1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="Item 2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
    ErrorMessage="Validation Message !" ControlToValidate="ddlItems" 
    InitialValue="-Day-"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Cool, never knew about the InitialValue property. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CompareValidator like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItems" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="-Day-" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1" Value="Item 1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="Item 2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="CompareFieldValidator1" 
    ErrorMessage="Validation Message !" ControlToValidate="ddlItems" 
    ValueToCompare="-1" Operator="NotEqual"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

-Edoode